# Extract TIME from DATETIME - informix

Tags: sql, timestamp, informix, etl

I have lost few hours looking for one row solution and didn't manage to find it.
I have some value `(2013/01/03 07:13:26.000)` and I want to extract time part to get this: `07:13:26` so I can store it in another database as stage layer in ETL process.

When I try `select my_datetime::datetime hour to second`, I still get full timestamp.

Thanks.

**EDIT: Sorry, source column is `datetime`, NOT timestamp.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do this:

```
SELECT to_char(extend (my_datetime_column, hour to second),'%H:%M:%S') as my_time FROM my_table
```

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(datetime_field AS DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND) ...
```

Or

```
SELECT to_char(datetime_field, "%H:%M:%S") ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

select cast(ColumnName as time) [time]
from yourtable

OR

select convert(char(5), ColumnName, 108) [time] from TableName

Comment: sql error. But I cannot see error number from this etl console.

Comment: I have added one more query to my reply. please give that a try. Second query will return you the hour:minutes only.

Comment: 'Type (time) Found' for first one.
'Routine (char) can not be unambiguously determined' for second query.
Maybe there is a problem in source data. Connection is jdbc.

Comment: mistake, source column is not timestamp, it's datetime

Comment: These suggestions are SQL Server syntax. Unfortunately, putting the `sql` tag in a question seems to attract SQL Server answers.